# How to create video using QTRLE codec in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

- I want to generate video using **QTRLE** codec and with **ARGB** pixel format using ffmpeg lib.
- I am able to create video using H264 with YUV420P pixel format, but unable to do same with QTRLE.So how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your first video, the one you create using H264 with YUV240p pixel format is a mp4, and I suppose that you want to also generate a MP4 video with the QTRLE codec and ARGB pixel format.

The problem is QTRLE codec is not compatible with the mp4 container, so you cannot have an mp4 file encoded in qtrle. The container I know compatible with it is MOV.  I tried it and there is no problem.